# Why "create! do" works in this model and not "new! do"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

**user.rb**:

```
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      # Add an error message when email is already taken
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
      user.password = user.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6) 
    end
  end
```

**sessions_controller.rb:**

```
 def omniauth_create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.save
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      #session[:omniauth] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra')
      redirect_to signup_path
      flash.now[:error] = 'Worked!'
    end
  end
```

Now this code doesn't work because `create! do` in the User model saves the user and an error is being thrown before the execution reaches the controller and pass through the if statement. So I thought of using `new! do` instead but got this:

```
undefined method `new!' for #<Class:0xb5aaf04>
```

Why "create! do" worked not "new! do"?

(I am taking the wrong approach to solve this? If so, what others solutions I can apply?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a `new!` method, I'm only aware of `create!` and `save!`

`new` and `build` just initialize the object without saving to the db, `save` does, and `create` does both initialization and saving.

The bang at the end is to raise an exception if an error occured instead of returning false.

So if you use `new` you'll have to `save!` for the record to persist.

```
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    pw = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6) 
    record = new(
      provider: auth["provider"],
      uid: auth["uid"],
      name: auth["info"]["name"],
      # Add an error message when email is already taken
      email: auth["info"]["email"],
      password: pw,
      password_confirmation: pw
    )
    record.save!
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! for the answer but what if i want to do "save!" in the if statement of the sessions controller? Is that possible?

Comment: I've added an explanation of the bang sign at the end of `create!` and `save!`.

Comment: If you use `save!` in the sessions controller then the `else` block would be useless.

Comment: Why would you use `save!` instead of `save`? `save!` would display a 500 internal error if the validation didn't pass through instead of your custom result.

Comment: Well I'm not sure, it the Railscast the author used `create!` so I assumed I had to use `save!`

Answer (score 0):

You can find what methods model has, run rails console and type: `ModelName.methods.sort`